# STL algorithms vs plain code

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, for-loop

I have a vector of objects:

```
std::vector<Object> data;
```

Now I need to call `Object::Foo()` in data array:

```
for (int i=0; i < data.size(); ++i) data[i].Foo(); // I think, the most slower
for (Object *it : data) it->Foo(); // And these are equal?
for (auto it=data.begin(); i!=data.end(); ++it) it->Foo();
```

I know about these methods, but now I'm learning STL and I found `for_each` there:

```
for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), mem_fun(&Object::Foo));
```

Which one is better? In other words, first 2 examples are more 'base' and it's easy to understand that constructions for common developer.

What about the speed of STL algorithms (and `for_each` with `mem_fun` in current case). Do I really need to learn it?

Comment: Don't think. Measure. Always profile. Optimization is for compilers, and code is for humans. Write for legibility. Code intent. Thank you very much

Comment: The second loop should probably read: `for ( Object & obj : data ) obj.Foo();`

Answer (score 5):

There won't be a discernable performance difference, when using a decent compiler.

```
for (int i=0; i < data.size(); ++i) 
    data[i].Foo();
```

Not slower, just profile that! Simple code tends to be quicker. In this case, all versions are equally simple

```
for (Object& it : data) 
    it.Foo();
```

Fixed that for you: use a reference to avoid unwanted copying(!). Also, this is roughly equivalent to:

```
{
    auto curr  = std::begin(data);
    auto endit = std::end(data);
    for (; curr != endit; ++curr) 
        curr.Foo();
}
```

#### STL antics

Regarding `mem_fun`/`mem_fun_ref` and related (`bind_1st`, `negate` etc), I suggest you don't *need* to learn them. It may be of interest to read up on them, but C++11 has solved these 'problems' in much more elegant ways.

```
// using std::bind
for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), std::bind(&Object::Foo, _1)); 

// using lambdas
for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [] (Object& o) { o.Foo(); });
```

Indeed, libraries (like Loki, Boost Bind, Boost Lambda and the more recent Boost Phoenix can make this equally succinct, even in C++03.

Comment: data.end() should be cached, not recalculated every time if you want to copy the semantics of the new for loop.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: I somehow lost my last edits because the question got deleted before posting. Give me a minute to recover those bits... Done

Answer (score 2):

> Which one is better?

Using `std::for_each()` is better in that it makes it easier to avoid silly errors like messing up iterators (using two referring to different sequences). But the `std::mem_func()` syntax is clumsy and unreadable, and composing more complex loop bodies this way inevitably leads to terribly unreadable code.

This is solved by C++11 introducing lambda functions:

```
std::for_each( data.begin(), data.end(), [](Object& obj){obj.Foo();} );
```

For me, this is clearly the winner. It's easy to read and makes it easy to spot when you mix different iterators.

> What about the speed of STL algorithms (and `for_each` with `mem_fun` in current case).

It's hard to say, depends on the implementation, and your compiler's ability to optimize. *If* this loop really matters, profile, find out, and throw out readability at the one spot it matters. Until then, readability trumps all other concerns.

Comment: I don't see how you can mess up iterators with `for (Object& o: data) {o.Foo(); }`. - There has to be some other reason to convince me to use `std::for_each`.

Comment: @UncleBens: That's true. I had forgotten about the new `for` syntax when I wrote this. `:(`

Answer (score 1):

The best code is the code that you don't have written.

So, use the STL with less code, it is compact and has a logical system.

**But more important is, that you keep one style and don't change it**. I personally use STL and never had problem.

And also the most code samples are written in STL, if you use it, you will understand the samples.

Answer (score 1):

Although there isn't much potential to optimize std::for_each() over a std::vector it may still be faster than the manual loop (including the version using the range-based for). For other containers and/or other algorithm the potential benefit is bigger.

The other important aspect is that you generally want to say **what** you are doing rather than **how** to do it: aside from the implementation having a possibly better approach to solve the problem, it make things more readable. Also, it seems that the error rate is dependent on the amount of code written with more code having more errors. This means that less code has fewer errors.

Answer (score 0):

The one you can do most reliably without error, and that others looking at will find easiest to understand is better.

In the longer run, it is good that you know how iterators work, and how things like `mem_fun` work.  Using the iterators will also enable your same code to be used if the collection object changes.